# Access uniquely-named Maven snapshot using ivysettings.xml in sbt?

Tags: sbt, ivy

I use an `ivysettings.xml` file to configure the repositories to use for `sbt`, which uses Ivy.

However, it's not able to download a particular snapshot which uses unique naming (i.e. date-based naming). It only tries the patterns listed explicitly in my `ivysettings.xml` file (which makes sense), so it can't see the details in `maven-metadata.xml` which tell it the filename of the snapshot jar to download.

I tried specifying the version explicitly instead of as a snapshot in `Build.scala`:

```
"com.jolbox" % "bonecp" % "0.8.1-20131105.191813-1"
```

(which would be my ideal solution, because then it would be cached in our maven repository and I'd be guaranteed to always use the same snapshot), but this generated the wrong URL (there should be an 0.8.1-SNAPSHOT in there, but of course there isn't):

```
http://maven/nexus/content/groups/softwaretools-snapshot-group/com/jolbox/bonecp/0.8.1-20131105.191813-1/bonecp-0.8.1-20131105.191813-1.pom
```

I then tried specifying the URL explicitly using `from`, but [this didn't work](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/978).

I then tried using `latest.integration` as the version, but that didn't correctly identify the latest version - it thought it was 0.8.0-rc1, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: This is a snapshot jar. Maven repositories are usually setup, so the SNAPSHOT jars are in a different virtual repository. You need to configure your `ivysettings.xml` to pull from this virtual snapshot repository. You can use pattern matching to pull from the snapshot repo if it's a snapshot jar. Let me know if you need more info on doing this.

Comment: @DavidW. I already have `softwaretools-snapshot-group` set up to include the mirror of that snapshot repository.

Comment: Can you include the relevant lines in `ivy.xml` and your `ivysettings.xml`? I'd like to try tweaking them to see if I can download this particular jar. We use Artifactory, and I have that configured, so the SNAPSHOT and release stuff are in the same virtual repo. This way, we only need to fetch from one local repository for all of our Jar needs.

Answer (score 1):

Download the dependency manually and add it to the `lib` directory of the project (create it if necessary); remove it from the `Build.scala` file.

Comment: +1 misery loves company, getting bitten by, "No operations allowed after connection closed" I presume? There must be a way to Pattern match the dependency, but yes, just download the damn jar into lib managed is acceptable quick & dirty ;-)

Comment: @virtualeyes No, I don't recognise that particular error! :) I listed all the things I tried in the question.

Comment: Yup, tried the same as you, mostly bumbling around in the dark (sadly the norm in SBT sans IDE support). Would be nice to get this working as a straight dependency and not relying on lib managed workaround.

Comment: @virtualeyes are you also using an ivysettings file?

Comment: oh, I assumed that the problem must be related to ivysettings, because I assumed that the basic functionality without ivysettings would work...

Comment: correction, nothing works, had to take the manual route (jar in lib managed). TBD whether bonecp 0.8.1 snapshot solves 0.8.0 issues...